# localhost на сервере - по какому адресу?

Tags: php, localhost

Здравствуйте.

Каким образом можно понять, по какому адресу находится localhost у сервера, который был заказан у какого-либо хостера, а не расположен у вас на ПК.

Опишу ситуацию: заливаю файл "robots.txt" в главную директорию одного из сайтов (файл не пустой), далее заливаю в директорию того же сайта файл "test.php", содержание которого:

```
<?php file_get_contents('http://localhost/var/www/user/data/www/moywebsite.ru/robots.txt'); ?>
```

Выдаёт ошибку:

```
PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(http://localhost/var/www/user/data/www/moywebsite.ru/robots.txt) [<a href='function.file-get-contents'>function.file-get-contents</a>]: failed to open stream: Connection refused in /var/www/user/data/www/moywebsite.ru/test.php on line 1
```

Как получить контент файла [robots.txt](http://robots.txt), не прибегая к file_get_contents('http://moywebsite.ru/robots.txt')? Т.е. меня интересует вариант file_get_contents('http://localhost/*').

Answer (score 4, accepted):

А что нибудь типа:

`$file = fopen("$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/robots.txt","r");
$cnt = fread ($file, 1024);
echo $cnt;`

или

`$file = file_get_contents("$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/robots.txt");`

не катит?